# Refresh view programmatically on admin-on-rest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I am trying to refresh a Resource's show view after completing a custom action on admin-on-rest lib.

But I don't see any API to do that. 
If I click manually in the "Refresh" button, it works.

Is there a way to refresh the view programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

In order to refresh the screen the state needs to be updated. The updated state can either be the local component state (via setState) or the state provided by the props (if using redux) needs to be updated. If you are using redux I would suggest raising an action that reloads the data from the server into the store.

Comment: This is true in general react but not specific to `admin-on-rest` which provides the means to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `this.forceUpdate()` function to refresh the component programmatically.

Src: [React-Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `refresh` redux action which is exported from `admin-on-rest`. If you have a custom saga which handle your action, just dispatch the `refresh` action after you're done